# Only activate Jquery function on second scroll movement on mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two `<div>`s.

On scroll, I would like `.indie` to disappear, and `.jazz` to appear.

Then, on the second scroll, I would like a 3rd div to appear.

At the moment, my Javascript hides both divs and I am trying to think of a way I can number each scroll movement to activate the visibility of each `<div>`. In numbering the scroll movements, I would also like to scroll up returning the 1st `<div>` again.

Currently my code looks like this. I am also using animate.css

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
       if ($('.indie').is(':visible')) {
             $('.fadeInRight').addClass("fadeOutLeft").removeClass("fadeInRight");
             $('.fadeInLeft').addClass("fadeOutRight").removeClass("fadeInLeft");
             $('.fadeInUp').addClass("fadeOutDown").removeClass("fadeInUp");
             $('.fadeInDown').addClass("fadeOutUp").removeClass("fadeInDown");
             $('.bounceOutRight').addClass("bounceInLeft").removeClass("bounceOutRight");
             $('.bounceOutLeft').addClass("bounceInRight").removeClass("bounceOutLeft");
             $('.bounceOutUp').addClass("bounceInDown").removeClass("bounceOutUp");
             $('.bounceOutDown').addClass("bounceInUp").removeClass("bounceOutDown");
             $('.jazz').css("visibility", "visible");
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $('.indie').css("visibility", "hidden");
              }, 500);
           }

  });



  $(window).scroll(function(){
           if ($('.jazz').is(':visible')) {
             $('.bounceInRight').addClass("bounceOutLeft").removeClass("bounceInRight");
             $('.bounceInLeft').addClass("bouneOutRight").removeClass("bounceInLeft");
             $('.bounceInUp').addClass("bounceOutDown").removeClass("bounceInUp");
             $('.bounceInDown').addClass("bounceOutUp").removeClass("bounceInDown");
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $('.jazz').css("visibility", "hidden");
              }, 500);
           }
  });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "second scroll"? Could you please provide a working [MCVE demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -2):

Place all your code into a single function, as the second declaration overwrites the first. I also made a few tweaks:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
       if ($('.indie').is(':visible')&&!$('.jazz').is(':visible')) {
             $('.fadeInRight').addClass("fadeOutLeft").removeClass("fadeInRight");
             $('.fadeInLeft').addClass("fadeOutRight").removeClass("fadeInLeft");
             $('.fadeInUp').addClass("fadeOutDown").removeClass("fadeInUp");
             $('.fadeInDown').addClass("fadeOutUp").removeClass("fadeInDown");
             $('.bounceOutRight').addClass("bounceInLeft").removeClass("bounceOutRight");
             $('.bounceOutLeft').addClass("bounceInRight").removeClass("bounceOutLeft");
             $('.bounceOutUp').addClass("bounceInDown").removeClass("bounceOutUp");
             $('.bounceOutDown').addClass("bounceInUp").removeClass("bounceOutDown");
             $('.jazz').css("visibility", "visible");
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $('.indie').css("visibility", "hidden");
              }, 500);
           }
           if ($('.jazz').is(':visible')) {
             $('.bounceInRight').addClass("bounceOutLeft").removeClass("bounceInRight");
             $('.bounceInLeft').addClass("bouneOutRight").removeClass("bounceInLeft");
             $('.bounceInUp').addClass("bounceOutDown").removeClass("bounceInUp");
             $('.bounceInDown').addClass("bounceOutUp").removeClass("bounceInDown");
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $('.jazz').css("visibility", "hidden");
              }, 500);
           }
  });
```

Comment: No, the second does not overwrite the first. When binding handlers to events through jQuery methods (*as is with `addEventListener`*) they all get executed when the event occurs.

Comment: You fixed something that didn't need fixing, but didn't fix the bits that could really do with some work. Where are the tweaks?